# Accept Matrix Header in Asp.net Core API

Tags: c#, matrix, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to pass matrix array as parament to API, it seems I am not passing the parameter in right way.

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Post")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]int[,] matrixValues)
{
}
```

I am passing the parameter as request body from swagger UI

```
[
  {1,0,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0 },{1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0,1}
]
```

It is throwing as

```
System.NotSupportedException: The type 'System.Int32[,]' is not supported.
```

Is there any way to accept matrix header in .Net core API?

Comment: Forget about swagger, every second complain is about it.

Answer (score 0):

Model Binding doesn't support this type of data , You can use custom Model Binding.

**Custom Model Binding**

```
public class CustomMB : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

            var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;   

            var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
            if (values.Length == 0)
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            var a  = (string)values;
            var b = "[" + a + "]";

             //add nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json`
            var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[,]>(b);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Then you can see when I add matrix array in swagger , action can receive the value.**
[image]

[image]